# Swift exception handling vs python exceptions

Tags: python, swift, exception

I started learning Swift yesterday coming from Python and Javascript (and VB.NET at school) and I have some trouble with the exception handling.

In Python I can just do this:

```
def myFunction(n):
    x = 3 / n
    return x

try:
    print(myFunction(0))
except Exception:
    print("Unexpected incident")
```

And it works as expected.
Whereas in Swift I try to do the same:

```
func myFunction(n:Int) throws -> Float {
    var a:Float
    a = 3 / n
    return a
}
do {
    try print(myFunction(0))
} catch {
    print("Unexpected incident")
}
```

I realize this must be a very dumb question but I just can't get it.
I read the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269395/swift-exceptions-to-exception-handling) and one answer is about the do/try/catch syntax (third one) but I still do not see what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the division operator throws an exception in swift.
You would have to manually throw the exception when `n == 0`

ie:

```
enum NumericalExceptions: ErrorType {
  case DivideByZero
}

func myFunction(n:Int) throws -> Float {
  guard n != 0 else {
    throw NumericalExceptions.DivideByZero
  }
  return 3 / Float(n)
}
do {
  try print(myFunction(0))
} catch {
  print("Unexpected incident")
}
```